# IOS Google Maps Get NorthEast and SouthWest Lat Long padded by certain size

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am able to get the NE and SW lat long from this.

```
bounds_ = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:mapView_.projection.visibleRegion];

CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bounds_.southWest.latitude, bounds_.southWest.longitude);

CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bounds_.northEast.latitude,bounds_.northEast.longitude);
```

How can I pad by Northeast and Southwest lat long by 25% so that I can pass the padded coordinates to an API and get an image slightly bigger than by screen view area.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the zoom level of your Mapview camera.

Sample Objective-C code:

```
[mapView_ animateToZoom:12];
```

For more information, you can read [the Zoom section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#zoom) of the Google Maps iOS page.